# SQL Server - Only show columns with data in them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a report that shows all of the SSRS (rdl) indicating what databases the reports use.  I have used sys.databases and the rdl content to create a table showing all of the reports with database names as column names.  (Client has over 100 databases.)  If a database was found within the rdl code I indicated it with an 'X'.

Here is an example:

```
Report Name      tempdb     Master   Test     Reports   Claims
My Report.rdl         X
Ur Report.rdl                           X           X
Master.rdl                                          X
```

Currently I am doing a while loop through the sys.databases and creating a dynamic SQL statement like this:

```
...
    Declare variables

    Set @SQLStatement equal to the beginning of the select with static columns

...
  While Loop

    SET @ColumnsSqlStatement = 'SELECT @Result = Count(*) 
                                from ##DatabasesUsed where ['
                                + @NAME + '] = ''X'''

    EXEC sp_executesql @ColumnsSqlStatement, N'@Result int out',
        @NumberOfXs OUT

    IF @NumberOfXs > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLStatement = @SQLStatement + ', DBU.['
                + LTRIM(RTRIM(@NAME)) + ']'
        END
  End Loop
```

I then execute @SQLStatement which returns only the columns with data.

```
 Report Name      tempdb     Test     Reports  
 My Report.rdl         X
 Ur Report.rdl                  X           X
 Master.rdl                                 X
```

I am looking for a set based solution to get rid of the while loop.  Something like this:

```
SELECT E.Name AS [Database],
(
    SELECT Count(*) FROM ##DatabasesUsed WHERE [E.Name] = 'X'
) AS [counts] 
FROM sys.databases E
```

Obviously this doesn't work but what I need is for the select to convert the E.Name to the value of E.Name.

I appreciate any help.  Maybe there is a completely different solution to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I realize that I didn't explain the bottom code.  I will use that snippet within a larger select that builds a dynamic SQL statement to build the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...I am using all temporary tables so you'll need to retrofit some of it to match your database tables (you should be able to copy and paste this and have it run just fine though for testing or whatever).  I have a few debugging SELECT statements in there too just to show the output along the way.  I hope that this helps!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#DBsUsed') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DBsUsed
CREATE TABLE #DBsUsed (REPORT_NAME VARCHAR(50), tempDb VARCHAR, [Master] VARCHAR, Test VARCHAR, Reports VARCHAR, Claims VARCHAR)
INSERT INTO #DBsUsed (REPORT_NAME, tempDb, Master, Test, Reports, Claims)
VALUES
    ('My Report.rdl', 'X', '', '', '', ''),
    ('Your Report.rdl', '', '', 'X', 'X', ''),
    ('Master.rdl', '', '', '', 'X', '')
SELECT *
FROM #DBsUsed
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#Temp_Columns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp_Columns
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Columns (COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50), HasData INT, SQLCommand VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #Temp_Columns (COLUMN_NAME, HasData, SQLCommand)
SELECT name, NULL, 'WHEN ''' + name + ''' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #DBsUsed WHERE ' + name + '=''X'')'
FROM tempDB.sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#DBsUsed')
    AND name <> 'REPORT_NAME'

SELECT *
FROM #Temp_Columns;

DECLARE @MasterCommand VARCHAR(MAX) = ( 'UPDATE #Temp_Columns SET HasData = CASE COLUMN_NAME ' + (SELECT SQLCommand + ' ' FROM #Temp_Columns FOR XML PATH('')) + ' END')
EXEC (@MasterCommand)

SELECT *
FROM #Temp_Columns

DELETE FROM #Temp_Columns
WHERE HasData = 0

DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(MAX), @FinalSelect VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @ColumnList = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME + ',' FROM #Temp_Columns FOR XML PATH (''))
SET @ColumnList = LEFT(@ColumnList, LEN(@ColumnList) - 1)
SET @FinalSelect = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnList + ' FROM #DBsUsed'
EXEC (@FinalSelect)
```

The last line (EXEC (@FinalSelect)) should get you the output that you are looking for.